# Questions about designing a "settings" page on which users can edit their profiles

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, react-redux

I am using React, Redux, and Firebase to build a website. Users can edit their profiles on the "settings" page. My design objective and approaches are the following:

**Design objective:**
Users' existing profile information (profile picture, name, and etc.) is displayed once the page is loaded.

**Approach:**
I set all users' data fields to empty strings/array in the state of the "settings" component and use mapStateToProps to pass into the component existing user profile and set the state using componentDidMount. Each data field has its own handleXXXChange so that if users do not change a data field, its existing value will be passed as its existing value to the Redux action object called editProfile that updates the user's document in Firebase.

**Problems I ran into:**
1. componentDidMount is only called once during the lifecycle of a component, so if the user refreshes the page all the fields in the state will be set to "undefined."
2. It is weird that when I clicked the "Upload Profile Image" button, the page "reloaded" itself and there was a question mark appearing at the end of the URL. Indeed, a window did pop up for users to select an image file, but the selected image failed to be uploaded to firebase storage. It is very weird because the exact same uploadImage and openFiles methods worked before I added componentDidMount to achieve the objective mentioned above.

Thank you so much for your patience and help!

**"Settings" component**

```
class Settings extends Component {  

        state = {
            firstname: "",
            lastname: "",
            gender: "",
            institution: "",
            role: "",
            selfdescription: "",
            areasofinterest: "",
            email: "",
            profileimage: ""
        };


        componentDidMount() {

           const { profile, auth } = this.props;
           const id = auth.uid;
           const image = firebase.storage().ref(`images/`+id);
           image.getDownloadURL().then((url) => this.setState({ profileimage: url }));
           this.setState({
                firstname: profile.first_name,
                lastname: profile.last_name,
                gender: profile.gender,
                institution: profile.institution,
                role: profile.role,
                selfdescription: profile.self_description,
                areasofinterest: profile.areas_of_interest,
                email: profile.email
           }
           )
        }

        handleSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const { auth } = this.props;
            this.props.editProfile(this.state, auth.uid, this.props.history);
        }

        uploadImage = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const image = e.target.files[0];
            const { auth } = this.props;
            firebase.storage().ref('images/'+auth.uid).put(image);
        }

        openFiles = (e) => {
            const input = document.getElementById("imageinput");
            input.click();
        }

        handleFirstNameChange = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.setState({ firstname: document.getElementById("fn").value });
        }

        handleLastNameChange = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.setState({ lastname : document.getElementById("ln").value });
        }

        ......

       render(){


        const { auth, profile } = this.props;

        return(
            <form>

                        <img src={firebase.storage().ref(`images/`+auth.uid).getDownloadURL()}></img>
                        <input type="file" id="imageinput" hidden="hidden" onChange={this.uploadImage}></input>
                        <button onClick={this.openFiles}>Upload Profile Image</button>

                        <span>First Name</span>
                        <input id="fn" type="text" placeholder={profile.first_name} onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange}></input>

                        <span><br/>Last Name</span>
                        <input id="ln" placeholder={profile.last_name} onChange={this.handleLastNameChange}></input>

                        ......

                        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Save</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        profile: state.firebase.profile,
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {editProfile} )(withRouter(Settings));
```

**"editProfile" Redux action object (I'm pretty sure this part is fine but just put it up to make my code more understandable):**

```
export const editProfile = (credentials, userid, history) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    const profile = getState().firebase.profile;
    firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(userid).update({
        first_name: credentials.firstname,
        last_name: credentials.lastname,
        gender: credentials.gender,
        institution: credentials.institution,
        role: credentials.role,
        self_description: credentials.selfdescription,
        areas_of_interest: credentials.areasofinterest,
        email: credentials.email
    })
    .then(() => {
        dispatch({ type: EDIT_SUCCESS });
        history.push(profile.profile_url);
    })
}
```

Comment: "It is weird that when I clicked the "Upload Profile Image" button, the page "reloaded" itself and there was a question mark appearing at the end of the URL." That means the browser submitted the form to the webserver the conventional way, you want to prevent that in a single page app with preventDefault on the submit or click event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Yea it fixed the issue: I did not include e.preventDefault() in my openFiles function. However, while the image was successfully uploaded to firebase storage, it did not show up on the page. Instead, only the default image icon was displayed. I am wondering what caused this problem. I am very sure that the code I have to fetch the image URL address from my firebase storage is correct because it worked previously.

Comment: Hm I can only guess what happens there, have you tried to dispatch EDIT_SUCCESS manually via redux devtools and checked if that triggers the mapStateToProps with a different `state.firebase.profile`? Bit confused about `history.push(profile.profile_url)`. Isn't the user already on the profile page when uploading an image?